# Complex numbers proof...

Tags: complex-numbers

For any two complex numbers Z and W. Prove that:
$$|Z|^2W-|W|^2Z=Z-W$$

if and only if:
$$Z=W \quad\text{or}\quad ZW^* = 1$$

Use the upper equation to derive any one of the lower equations.

Comment: What did you try? Where are you struggling?

Comment: Let $z = x_1 + iy_1$ and $w = x_2 + iy_2$ and change accordingly.

Comment: @Ed_4434 .. it will turn far more complex

Comment: @MichaelBurr... edited it... missed out the squares

Comment: By $W^*$ what do you mean? The conjugate?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Rearrange to get:
$$W(|Z|^2 +1) = Z(|W|^2+1)$$ 
Since the quantities in t brackets are real scalars, we must have that $W$ and $Z$ are parallel vectors in $\mathbb{C}$, i.e. $Z=\lambda W$. Now show that $\lambda$ can only be...

Comment: you mean $Z$ and $W$ are parallel vectors. More important, question has now been edited. I recommend you update this asap, or it will start getting downvoted ...

Comment: @almagest - Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$z=r_1e^{i\theta_1}, w=r_2e^{i\theta_2}$$
It follows that $$(r_1)^2r_2e^{i\theta_2}-(r_2)^2r_1e^{i\theta_1}=r_1e^{i\theta_1}-r_2e^{i\theta_2}\\r_1^2r_2e^{i\theta_2}+r_2e^{i\theta_2}=r_2^2r_1e^{i\theta_1}+r_1e^{i\theta_1}\\e^{i\theta_2}(r_1^2r_2+r_2)=e^{i\theta_1}(r_2^2r_1+r_1)\\e^{i(\theta_2-\theta_1)}=\frac{r_2^2r_1+r_1}{r_1^2r_2+r_2}$$
Thus, $$\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)+i\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2)=\frac{r_2^2r_1+r_1}{r_1^2r_2+r_2}$$
which can only hold if $\theta_1-\theta_2=k\pi$ for $k \in \Bbb{Z}$ 

So we have $$\frac{r_2^2r_1+r_1}{r_1^2r_2+r_2}=1\Rightarrow\\r_2^2r_1+r_1=r_1^2r_2+r_2\Rightarrow\\(r_2-r_1)(r_1r_2-1)=0$$
it follows that either $r_1=r_2=r$ or $r_1=\frac{1}{r_2}$ and $$z=re^{i\theta_1}, w=re^{i(k\pi-\theta_1)}=re^{i\theta_1}=z$$or
$$z=re^{i\theta_1}, w=\frac1re^{i\theta_1}$$
So $$z=w$$ or $$z \bar w=r\frac1re^{i(k\pi-\theta_1)+i\theta_1}=e^0=1$$

Comment: Good someone please  explain the downvotes? (Both in my answer and the similar one by GoodDeeds).

Comment: isnt there a simpler way?

Comment: @prog_SAHIL Honestly I do not know. I am an undergrad myself with a single complex analysis course behind me. Perhaps someone else could provide a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Z=r_1e^{i\theta_1}$ and $W=r_2e^{i\theta_2}$.
Rearranging the given terms,
$$\frac{Z}{|Z|^2+1}=\frac{W}{|W|^2+1}$$
Substituting,
$$\frac{r_1e^{i\theta_1}}{r_1^2+1}=\frac{r_2e^{i\theta_2}}{r_2^2+1}$$
$$r_1r_2^2e^{i\theta_1}+r_1e^{i\theta_1}=r_1^2r_2e^{i\theta_2}+r_2e^{i\theta_2}$$
$$r_1r_2(r_2e^{i\theta_1}-r_1e^{i\theta_2})=r_2e^{i\theta_2}-r_1e^{i\theta_1}$$
$$(r_1e^{i\theta_1})(r_2e^{-i\theta_2})(r_2e^{i\theta_2}-r_1e^{i(2\theta_2-\theta_1)})=r_2e^{i\theta_2}-r_1e^{i\theta_1}$$
$$ZW^*(r_2e^{i\theta_2}-r_1e^{i(2\theta_2-\theta_1)})=W-Z$$
The statement in the question would be satisfied if $(r_2e^{i\theta_2}-r_1e^{i(2\theta_2-\theta_1)})$ evaluated to $W-Z$, that is, $r_2e^{i\theta_2}-r_1e^{i\theta_1}$. But that gives an additional condition that $$2\theta_2-\theta_1=\theta_1+2k\pi\Rightarrow\theta_2=\theta_1+k\pi$$

Comment: May I know the reason for the downvote? If anything is wrong I will delete this answer.

Comment: I am having the same issue with the downvote. Our approach is similar and I can't see which step is wrong..Strange..